# What is our stance on questions about software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about software recommendations?  Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/9084/43):

> Title: Does Canada have the Good RX app?
>
> I recently moved to Canada from the USA, and I was curious whether Canada, specifically British Columbia, has the Good RX app. Do any of you know? Or does an app not exist because the cost of the prescription drugs are regulated by the government?

Answer (score 4):

There is a site specifically for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This type of question would be better suited for there. I've asked their moderators if it is up to their standards, if it is, I will migrate it. If not, I would VTC as I agree with Carey Gregory, it's not really on topic for us.